# Rotation to a given direction in opengl

Tags: opengl, rotation

I'm starting to confuse math.

I want to make a rotation that translates the direction of the y axis to a given direction.

So I want to make a function that has a direction for input, and makes a call to glRotatef(). After the function anything I draw should point to the given direction instead of upwards.

glRotatef has 4 parameters: angle, x, y, z

Comment: If you confused *math* itself, that's an achievement... Anyway, your question is far from specific. SO won't learn OpenGL and maths for you, sorry. Get a tutorial and work through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to align the world `y` axis with a (unit-length) direction `d`.  In order to compose a rotation matrix with glRotatef, you need an axis `a = [a_x, a_y, a_z]` and an angle `omega`.

The rotation axis that takes `y` into `d` is perpendicular to both `y` and `d`, thus can be computed via the vector cross product:

```
a = cross(y, d);
```

the angle of rotation `omega` is simply the angle between the vectors `y` and `d`, thus can be computed from the dot product:

```
omega = acos(dot(y, d));
```

Now you can build your rotation matrix with:

```
glRotatef(omega, a_x, a_y, a_z);
```

Be careful that `omega` needs to be in degrees and not radians.  Also check the direction of rotation.

Comment: Thanks! But the cross product is very strange if d = Vector(0, -1, 0) (points to the opposite direction than the y axis). Should I specifically check for that?

Comment: Yes, in that case you should choose an arbitrary unit-vector on the `xz` plane, such as the x axis.